# How fix error 404 on power apps custom conector test

Tags: elasticsearch, powerapps

I'm making a custom connector with an Elasticserach API and when testing the connector, the following error appears[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeDrb.png). The URL show me the following message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq9Yj.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please embed images in your question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted your token in the body. Your token should be submitted via the header.

Comment: would you have any example ?

Comment: I don’t know what type of access token you try to submit: Bearer eyGshe type?

Comment: i use Basic auth to make the authorization so i don´t have a token. i should change to Oauth 2.0 ?